# Ruby function in Chef source code reads argument incorrectly

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

My code makes a function call [in Chef](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/resource/package.rb) that takes in some parameters:

```
property :version, [ String, Array ]
```

The [function](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mixin/properties.rb) called is defined like this:

```
def property(name, type = NOT_PASSED, **options)
      #below is debugging code I added
      if name==:version
        raise "type: #{type}, options: #{options}, caller: #{caller}"
      end
```

The debugging code you see above, when executed, spits out some parameters and the call-stack:

```
type: {String=>nil, Array=>nil}, options: {}, caller: ["[a-secret-path]/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource/package.rb:38:in `<class:Package>'...
```

As you can see, even though the function call passes in [String, Array], the function interprets the "type" variable as {String => nil, Array => nil}. Why does this happen?

### OPTIONAL READING BELOW

My hypotheses and what I've done to test them:

1) I thought the property() function might be called from somewhere other than the place I identify. However, printing out the caller shows it is called from the line I cite: "property :version, [ String, Array ]"

2) I thought the default argument for "type" might be interacting in a strange way with the "double splat" argument "**options," so I wrote a test file:

```
def take_in_double_splat(name, type = NOT_PASSED, **options)
  puts "type: #{type}, options: #{options}"
end

take_in_double_splat :version, [ String, Array ]
```

Executing the file produces the expected output:

```
type: [String, Array], options: {}
```

Two final experiments I did are worth noting:

1) Removing the default value from the argument in the Chef code fixes the problem, allowing us to read in [String, Array] rather than {String => nil, Array => nil}. I do this like so:

```
def property(name, type, **options)
```

2) Adding an argument to the function call also fixes the problem. For example:

```
property :version, [ String, Array ], random: 'hi'
```